# Grid inside Grid in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to have a childGrid in second column of parentGrid (in childGrid I want to have two columns: first for label, second for textbox)

How can I do Something like that? I tried the following code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column=1>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Height="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Based on your code, just fixed up a little:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Note that `ColumnDefinition` don't have a *Height* - they have a *Width*. You also need to define the ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions separately - you have them mixed together in your outer grid. I removed the RowDefinitions from the outer grid because you don't appear to be using them. Your inner grid has two columns and four rows.

Comment: How do I place controls in the inner grid?

Comment: @Gener4tor Use the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached properties on the control. As this is a comment I have to be brief, but it'll look something like this: `<Grid><Grid.ColumnDefinitions /><Grid.RowDefinitions /><TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">some test</TextBox></Grid>` Of course you'd have some row/column definitions in there, I left them empty for the sake of brevity. Remember that the row/column count is zero based.

Comment: ok. Got it. The Grid.Row="1" and Grid.Column="2" is always refering to the most inner grid.

Comment: How does the code know which Grid control you're referencing the row and column of? This doesn't seem to be a clear answer. Can you show a couple of controls on each Grid in different positions?

Comment: @omJohn8372 the row/column placements are in the context of the grid the control (or grid) is a child of.So yes, you can have more controls/grids in each of the two grids illustrated above.

Comment: So the implication then is that you have to put your child elements into it in the XAML and organize them within the appropriate Grid. I suppose that makes pretty good sense, but wasn't the way I've organized my code in the past, if memory serves.

Answer (score 9):

You might find this useful.  Try pasting this into a page using Kaxaml and playing around with the various parameters of the objects in the outer Grid.  I find using Kaxaml for prototyping and experimenting with XAML layouts indispensable.

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <!-- 
     When I'm composing grids in XAML, I group things together by type, not by where
     they live in the grid.  This turns out to make a lot of maintenance tasks
     easier.

     Also, since Grid.Row and Grid.Column default to 0, a lot of people (and tools)
     omit them if that's their value.  Not me.  It lets me quickly check to make
     sure that content is where I think it is, just by looking at how it's organized
     in the XAML.
  -->

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Lavender" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Here's the first row of the outer grid.</TextBlock>
  <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Lavender" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">Here's the third row of the outer grid.</TextBlock>

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="10">Here's the first column of the second row.</TextBlock>

  <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <!--
         This part's pretty important.  Setting up the SharedSizeGroups for these
         two columns keeps the labels and text boxes neatly arranged irrespective of
         their length.
      -->
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Label"/>
      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="TextBox"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">First label</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Second label</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">Third label, containing unusually long content</Label>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">First text box, containing unusually long content</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Second text box</TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">Third text box</TextBox>

  </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

It might come a little confusing how to put controls in sub grids. Here is an example.

We have 3 * 3 cell grid. And then center cell is further divided in 3 rows where each row has a button.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="Button1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button2"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button3"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Phenevo, I've done XAML UI design extensively this year.  Try this out, you can easily migrate the code to either a Window or a UserControl.  I color-coded the grids and panels so that you could affirm their layout in real time -- blow away the background parameters when you're satisfied.

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="UatControlLibrary.sampleChilGrid"
    x:Name="UserControl"
    MinWidth="400"
    MinHeight="300"
    Width="auto"
    Height="auto">
    <Grid
        x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid
            x:Name="parentGrid"
            Width="auto"
            Height="auto"
            Background="Red">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="1*" />
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="1*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid
                x:Name="chilGrid"
                Width="auto"
                Height="auto"
                Background="Black"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="1*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition
                        Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="stkpnlLabels"
                    Background="White"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.Row="0" />
                <StackPanel
                    x:Name="stkpnlTextboxes"
                    Background="Blue"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="0" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```